# Firebase Cloud Function unit test HTTP onCall

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I would like to write some unit tests for a bunch of cloud functions. Now I'm facing the following issue. Using the `firebase-functions-test` I'm somehow not able to test HTTP triggered cloud functions. Here are some of my cloud functions that i'd like to test using `jest`:

```
export cloudFunctions = {
    createUserByAdmin: functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: '256MB' }).https.onCall(UserService.createUserByAdmin),
    updateUserByAdmin: functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: '256MB' }).https.onCall(UserService.updateUserByAdmin),
    deleteUserByAdmin: functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: '256MB' }).https.onCall(UserService.deleteUserByAdmin)
}
```

They are all deployed on Firebase and they work without problems. But I couldn't find a way to call the using the `firebase-functions-test` package. Also, there are a few examples of how to write unit tests using that package but none of them test http triggered functions.

This is my test file:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions-test'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as path from 'path'

const projectConfig = {
    projectId: 'test-fb',
}

const testEnv = functions(
    projectConfig,
    path.resolve('DO-NOT-EDIT.dev.fb-admin-sdk-key.json'),
)

describe('[Cloud Functions] User Service', () => {
    let cloudFunctions

    beforeAll(() => {
        cloudFunctions = require('../index')
    })

    afterAll(() => {
      // delete made accounts/entrys
    })

    describe('Testing "createUserByAdmin"', () => {
        it('Creating User does work', () => {
            expect(1).toBe(0)
        })
    })
})
```

Does someone know how to test http cloud functions? I would really appreciate an example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually found a way on how to test HTTP Cloud Functions using `firebase-functions-test` it all works with a wrapper function. Take a look at this [reference page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/test/test#.wrap). Here is some code to make things a bit more clear.

**this is a snippet from one of my tests**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions-test'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as path from 'path'

const projectConfig = {
    projectId: 'myproject-id',
}

const testEnv = functions(
    projectConfig,
    path.resolve('fb-admin-sdk-key.json'),
)
// has to be after initializing functions
import * as cloudFunctions from '../index'

describe('Testing "createUserByAdmin"', () => {
        const createUserByAdmin = testEnv.wrap(cloudFunctions.createUserByAdmin)

        it('Creating User does work', async (done) => {
            const data = {
                displayName: 'Jest Unit Test',
                email: 'unit@domain.com',
                password: 'password',
                uid: null,
            }
            const context = {
                auth: {
                    token: {
                        access: 'somestring,
                    },
                    uid: 'mockuiddddd',
                },
            }
            await createUserByAdmin(data, context)
                .then(async (createdUser: any) => {
                    expect(createdUser.status).toBe('OK')
                    done()
                })
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    fail('createUserByAdmin failed with the following ' + error)
                })
        })
    })
```

You'll see that after initializing our test environment using our `projectConfig` and our service account key file.

```
const testEnv = functions(
    projectConfig,
    path.resolve('fb-admin-sdk-key.json'),
)
```

you'll just have to wrap the appropriate cloud function with the `.wrap()` function.

`const createUserByAdmin = testEnv.wrap(cloudFunctions.createUserByAdmin)`

And you can call it like every other function (keep in mind that cloud functions usually expect a data parameter (with the variables you use in your cloud function) as well as a context parameter, depending on how you handle authentication/authorization you'll have to try and error to find the right context properties your function requests.

**if your writing tests for your production cloud functions make sure to clean up after running tests - such as deleting created accounts or deleting data in either firestore or realtime-database**